# Apollo 3.3.2 kotlin escape from optional values in kmm

Tags: kotlin, graphql, apollo, kotlin-multiplatform

i have a kmm project which using **apollo graphql version 3.3.2**

Everything okay with the previous apollo version but the new version i have to set variables with **Optional.presentIfNotNull($variable)** like this.

```
  val officeId = QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions(
            Optional.presentIfNotNull(TrainingColumn.OFFICE_ID),
            Optional.presentIfNotNull(SQLOperator.IS_NULL)
        )
```

Before when i use **apollo v2** it was like this

```
  val officeId = QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions(
                TrainingColumn.OFFICE_ID,
                SQLOperator.IS_NULL
            )
```

**i tried to set**

```
generateOptionalOperationVariables.set(false) and try with true
```

in gradle file but it didn't work

and when i click the **QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions**

apollo generated the code like this

```
public data class QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions(
  /**
   * The column that is used for the condition.
   */
  public val column: Optional<TrainingColumn?> = Optional.Absent,
  /**
   * The operator that is used for the condition.
   */
  public val `operator`: Optional<SQLOperator?> = Optional.Absent,
  /**
   * The value that is used for the condition.
   */
  public val `value`: Optional<Any?> = Optional.Absent,
  /**
   * A set of conditions that requires all conditions to match.
   */
  public val AND: Optional<List<QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions>?> = Optional.Absent,
  /**
   * A set of conditions that requires at least one condition to match.
   */
  public val OR: Optional<List<QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditions>?> = Optional.Absent,
  /**
   * Check whether a relation exists. Extra conditions or a minimum amount can be applied.
   */
  public val HAS: Optional<QueryTrainingsForUserWhereWhereConditionsRelation?> = Optional.Absent,
)
```

i couldn't remember what was the generated code before **with apollo v2**.

it's very hard to use this `Optional.presentIfNotNull`. method in everywhere and i dont want to use this

**Is there any solution to fix my problem or any other way to use Optional.presentIfNotNull to handle optional variables ?**

Thanks

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: any workaround?